# Clean up string and move the noun before the comma

Tags: javascript, regex, functional-programming

I would like to know how I could improve the regex part of this script?

I now chain 4 replace methods which is not optimal. Any ideas of other improvement I'm happy to receive.

```js
const strings = [
  "ACTUATOR-BRK",
  "FLANG-SPLIT",
  "O-RING",
  "BOLT,M6X25MM HF",
  "BOLT,M6-1.0",
  "SCREW.CAP 444 44.4 ff.",
  "SCREW.CAP 444",
  "SCREW;CAP",
  "BOLT,M6-1.0",
  "screw and washer assembly (sems)",
  "screw",
  "angular contact (rolling) bearing",
  "Thrust bearings",
  "Thrust bear.",
  "Tensioner bearing",
  "screw,cap ff",
  "END bearing, ddfdfdf",
  "Tapped base bearing",
  "Load bearing element 1",
  "end bracket, testing",
  "Hanger bearings",
  "Flanged bearings",
  "screw,cap",
  "Angular contact bearing",
  "double-row (rolling) bearing",
  "screw,cap",
  "end bracket, bearing bracket (US)",
  "external-aligning (rolling) bearing",
  "filling slot (ball) bearing",
  "screw,cap",
  "#2 Heating fuel oil",
  "#4 or #6 Residual heavy fuel oils",
  "Aluminum SAE 6000 series hot rolled coil",
  "Aluminum, Reroll, Capacitor Foil Alloy 1145",
  "Aluminum, Sheet, Coiled Coated, Except Conductor & Decorative For Stamping",
  "700-R NEMA sealed industrial control relay",
  "802R NEMA 13 sealed contact",
  "802XR NEMA 7/9 hazardous location sealed contact",
  "Diaphragm seals",
  "Die cut seal kit",
  "MOTOR          STARTER",
  "V ring seal",
  "lip seal",
  "rotary shaft lip-type seal",
  "rubber-covered rotary shaft lip-type seal",
  "seal, O-ring",
  "seal kit",
  "motor with standardized mounting dimensions",
  "Connector to screw",
  "Earthing lug for cable screw gland",
  "Orthodontic expansion screws",
  "Self drilling tapping screw",
  "screw assembly",
  "BOLT,M6-1.0",
  "BOLT,HEX METRIC M6",
  "BOLT M6X25MM",
  "BOLT,M6X25MM HF",
  "NUT HEX FLG M6 1.0",
  "NUT HEX LOCK M6X1.0.00",
  "NUT,JAM,M6-1",
  "SCREW;CAP",
  "MOUNT,CALIBER,50,M6",
  "COVER",
  "BRACKET",
  "BRACKET",
  "RING-SNAP"
];

const abbreviations = [
  { abbreviation: "ASSY", expansion: "ASSEMBLY" },
  { abbreviation: "ASSY.", expansion: "ASSEMBLY" },
  { abbreviation: "ASY", expansion: "ASSEMBLY" },
  { abbreviation: "ASSY.", expansion: "ASSEMBLY" },
  { abbreviation: "BEAR.", expansion: "BEARING" },
  { abbreviation: "BRK", expansion: "BREAK" },
  { abbreviation: "TERMNL", expansion: "TERMINAL" },
  { abbreviation: "BRG", expansion: "BEARING" },
  { abbreviation: "ATTACH.", expansion: "ATTACHMENT" },
  { abbreviation: "BRKT", expansion: "BRAKET" },
  { abbreviation: "CORDGRIP", expansion: "CORD GRIP" },
  { abbreviation: "COMPL.", expansion: "COMPLETE" },
  { abbreviation: "CAPSCREW", expansion: "CAP SCREW" },
  { abbreviation: "CPLG", expansion: "COUPLING" },
  { abbreviation: "CYL", expansion: "CYLINDER" },
  { abbreviation: "CYL.", expansion: "CYLINDER" },
  { abbreviation: "CYLIND", expansion: "CYLINDER" },
  { abbreviation: "CYLIND.", expansion: "CYLINDER" },
  { abbreviation: "CYLINDE", expansion: "CYLINDER" },
  { abbreviation: "FILT.", expansion: "FILTER" },
  { abbreviation: "FRICT.", expansion: "FRICTION" },
  { abbreviation: "HD", expansion: "HEAD" },
  { abbreviation: "HD.", expansion: "HEAD" },
  { abbreviation: "CART.", expansion: "CARTRIDGE" },
  { abbreviation: "CARTR.", expansion: "CARTRIDGE" },
  { abbreviation: "HYD.", expansion: "HYDRAULIC" },
  { abbreviation: "HYDR.", expansion: "HYDRAULIC" },
  { abbreviation: "REDUC.", expansion: "REDUCER" },
  { abbreviation: "REGUL.", expansion: "REGULATOR" },
  { abbreviation: "FLG", expansion: "FLANGE" }
];

const _stringSplit = stringToSplit => {
  // check if the delimiter is a comma (the string most likely starts with a NOUN)
  if (stringToSplit.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
    return stringToSplit.replace(",", " ").toUpperCase();
    // check if the delimiter is a semicolon (the string most likely starts with a NOUN)
  } else if (stringToSplit.indexOf(";") >= 0) {
    return stringToSplit.replace(";", " ").toUpperCase();
  } else {
    // The string most likely ends with a NOUN
    return stringToSplit.toUpperCase().split(" ");
  }
};

const _findAbbreviations = (string, abbreviationsArray) => {
  const stringArray = _stringSplit(string);

  const abbreviationMatches = [];
  abbreviationsArray.forEach(item => {
    if (stringArray.indexOf(item.abbreviation) >= 0) {
      abbreviationMatches.push({
        abbreviation: item.abbreviation.toUpperCase(),
        expansion: item.expansion.toUpperCase()
      });
    }
  });
  return abbreviationMatches;
};

const _replaceAbbreviations = (string, abbreviationsArray) => {
  if (_findAbbreviations.length > 0) {
    const abbreviationMatches = _findAbbreviations(string, abbreviationsArray);
    let newString = string.toUpperCase();
    abbreviationMatches.forEach(item => {
      item.abbreviation[item.abbreviation.length - 1] === "."
        ? (abb = item.abbreviation.replace(/.$/, "\\."))
        : (abb = item.abbreviation);
      re = new RegExp(abb);
      newString = newString.replace(re, item.expansion);
    });
    return newString;
  } else {
    return string;
  }
};

const _regexString = (string, abbreviationsArray) => {
  const filterPattern1 = /[^a-zA-Z;,.]+/g; // find all non English alphabetic characters.
  const filterPattern2 = /\b\w{1,2}\b/g; // find words that are less then three characters long.
  const filterPattern4 = /\s\s+/g; // find multiple whitespace, tabs, newlines, etc.
  const filterPattern3 = /(,|\.)\s*$/;
  const filteredString = _replaceAbbreviations(string, abbreviationsArray)
    .toUpperCase()
    .replace(filterPattern1, " ")
    .replace(filterPattern2, match => {
      let abbr = abbreviationsArray.find(x => x.abbreviation === match);
      return abbr ? abbr.expansion : "";
    })
    .replace(filterPattern3, "")
    .replace(filterPattern4, " ")
    .trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespace.
  return filteredString;
};

const stringOrganizer = (stringArray, abbreviationsArray) => {
  const newStringArray = [];
  const nounsArray = [];

  const addNounToArray = noun => {
    const i = noun.indexOf(",");
    const firstTerm = i === -1 ? noun : noun.substring(0, i);

    if (nounsArray.indexOf(firstTerm) === -1) {
      nounsArray.push(firstTerm);
    }
  };

  const _delimiterFixer = (delimiter, string, abbreviationsArray) => {
    // exist a comma in the string
    const cleanedString = _regexString(string, abbreviations);
    const textAfterDelimiter = cleanedString
      .substring(cleanedString.indexOf(delimiter) + 1)
      .trim();
    const textBeforeDelimiter = cleanedString
      .replace(textAfterDelimiter, "")
      .replace(delimiter, "")
      .trim();
    const newString = textAfterDelimiter.length
      ? `${textBeforeDelimiter}, ${textAfterDelimiter
          .replace(/(,|\.)\s*$/, "")
          .trim()}`
      : textBeforeDelimiter.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
    newStringArray.push(newString);
    addNounToArray(newString);
  };
  // const fixedStrings = [];
  stringArray.forEach(string => {
    if (_regexString(string, abbreviations).indexOf(",") >= 0) {
      // exist a comma in the string
      _delimiterFixer(",", string);
    } else if (_regexString(string, abbreviations).indexOf(";") >= 0) {
      // exist a semicolon in the string
      _delimiterFixer(";", string);
    } else if (_regexString(string, abbreviations).indexOf(".") >= 0) {
      _delimiterFixer(".", string);
    } else if (string.trim().indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
      // exist only space(s) in the string;
      const cleanedString = _regexString(string, abbreviations);
      if (cleanedString.length > 0) {
        const noun = cleanedString.match(/\b(\w+)$/g).join(""); // \b(\w+)$ find last word in the string (the noun in this case).

        const textBeforeDelimiter = cleanedString.replace(noun, "").trim();
        const newString = noun.length
          ? `${noun}, ${textBeforeDelimiter}`.replace(/,\s*$/, "")
          : noun.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
        newStringArray.push(newString);
        addNounToArray(newString);
      } else {
        newStringArray.push("This part has some issues!");
      }
    } else {
      const newString = _regexString(string, abbreviations);
      newStringArray.push(newString.replace(/,\s*$/, ""));
      addNounToArray(newString);
    }
  });
  return [newStringArray.sort(), nounsArray.sort()];
};

console.log(stringOrganizer(strings, abbreviations)[0]);
console.log(stringOrganizer(strings, abbreviations)[1]);
```

Comment: See [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](//stackoverflow.com/a/15604206) for an example of generic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Unnecessary repeated evaluations

This is very inefficient:

> ```
> if (_regexString(string, abbreviations).indexOf(",") >= 0) {
>   // exist a comma in the string
>   _delimiterFixer(",", string);
> } else if (_regexString(string, abbreviations).indexOf(";") >= 0) {
>   // exist a semicolon in the string
>   _delimiterFixer(";", string);
> } else if (_regexString(string, abbreviations).indexOf(".") >= 0) {
>   _delimiterFixer(".", string);
> } else if (string.trim().indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
> ```

The `_regexString` function is not a cheap call,
but it's potentially repeated for every branch of the conditional with the same parameters. The solution is very simple:
call `_regexString(string, abbreviations)` before the conditional,
store in a local variable,
and use that variable in the `.indexOf(...)` calls in the conditional statements.

This kind of issue appears in other parts of the code as well, for example here:

> ```
> console.log(stringOrganizer(strings, abbreviations)[0]);
> console.log(stringOrganizer(strings, abbreviations)[1]);
> ```

Again, the result of `stringOrganizer(strings, abbreviations)` should be saved in a variable.

#### Choice of data structures

Why is `abbreviations` an array instead of an object where abbreviations are properties and expanded words are values.
When expanding abbreviations,
the implementation uses `.find(...)` in this array to find a match by the `abbreviation` property,
but this is a linear search.
It would be faster with an object.

#### Suspicious return value of `stringToSplit`

Judging by the name of the function,
and the return types of the first two branches of the conditional,
I would expect this function to return a string,
but in the `else` branch it returns an array:

> ```
> const _stringSplit = stringToSplit => {
>   // check if the delimiter is a comma (the string most likely starts with a NOUN)
>   if (stringToSplit.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
>     return stringToSplit.replace(",", " ").toUpperCase();
>     // check if the delimiter is a semicolon (the string most likely starts with a NOUN)
>   } else if (stringToSplit.indexOf(";") >= 0) {
>     return stringToSplit.replace(";", " ").toUpperCase();
>   } else {
>     // The string most likely ends with a NOUN
>     return stringToSplit.toUpperCase().split(" ");
>   }
> };
> ```

Perhaps that's a bug? The `.split(" ")` at the end is a mistake?
Or maybe all branches should return an array?
It's strange when a function can return different types (string vs. array in this example).

#### Splitting a string at delimiter

The `_delimiterFixer` extracts the part the string before the delimiter in a very strange way, using string replacements:

> ```
> const textBeforeDelimiter = cleanedString
>   .replace(textAfterDelimiter, "")
>   .replace(delimiter, "")
>   .trim();
> ```

It would be better to use `.substring(...)`:

```
const textBeforeDelimiter = cleanedString.substring(0, delimiterIndex).trim();
```